# How do I prevent a runPendingTask script being included in returned HTML via ajax?

Tags: categories, routes, ajax

I have created a route to retrieve some categories via AJAX. When the AJAX call returns the HTML a runPendingTask script is also returned with the HTML. How do I prevent this?

```
/*<![CDATA[*/
(function() {
    var XMLHttpFactories = [
        function() {
            return new XMLHttpRequest()
        },
        function() {
            return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
        },
        function() {
            return new ActiveXObject("Msxml3.XMLHTTP")
        },
        function() {
            return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        }
    ];
    var req = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < XMLHttpFactories.length; i++) {
        try {
            req = XMLHttpFactories[i]();
        } catch (e) {
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    if (!req) return;
    req.open('GET',
        "http:\/\/tfc.dev\/hollywood-road\/index.php\/actions\/tasks\/runPendingTasks",
        true);
    if (req.readyState == 4) return;
    req.send();
})(); /*]]>*/
```

Comment: Per Brad's answer, closing this as a "bug report".

Answer (score 1):

The next (post [2.5.2767](https://craftcms.com/changelog#build2767) release) will no longer inject that code on AJAX requests.

Comment: Brad, possible this is showing up again with the latest 3.3.0.1 release?

Comment: Shouldn't be: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/queue/Queue.php#L474-L477

Comment: I'm seeing this at the bottom of certain frontend pages in 3.4.9 on pages that aren't performing any ajax requests.

Comment: @cmal did you resolve this? I am seeing the same as you on 3.4.20